# Is there a shorter synonym for "extra-curricular activities"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I always find the expression "extra-curricular activities" very clumsy.

Comment: Could you please provide some examples?

Comment: No. There seems to be no other expression that gives exactly the same meaning as 'extra-curricular activities'. It's not that clumsy, only a bit long.

Comment: Colloquially, _sex_ is often a good, brief synonym.

Comment: ‘Extra-curricular activities’ is sometimes used in slang as a euphemism for doing things you’re not really supposed to be doing, more specifically (in the case of a school kid) having sex. Describing a girl as “spending most of her school time on _extra-curricular activities_” can be a way of euphemistically calling her a slut.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Where *slut* is just a euphemism for someone who has more sex than the speaker. :)

Comment: What @JanusBahsJacquet says is true. However, it is also true that virtually all official language (and this is **very** official) can be used (and therefore **has** been used) as a euphemism for something that's taboo. One takes that for granted. Especially in writing, where there's no intonation to distinguish taboo uses from innocent ones.

Comment: @tchrist - There are no sluts in the world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fun stuff.  Hobbies.  Outside activities.  After school stuff.  It would help to know the context, so as to know how formal it needs to be.

Answer (score 3):

I've heard people who elide the *activities*, calling them *extracurriculars*.

Comment: extracurriculars means outside your career or daily routine.  It has a different meaning outside the context.  Just FYI for non-native speakers.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes they are referred to *after school activities*, you could just call them *clubs and sports*, maybe *nonscholastic* activities.   You are talking about all activities that happen at a school outside of normal classes.  Not sure there is a nice short word for this.

Answer (score 0):

*Supplementary education* can also be a synonym as its an important part along with education.

Answer (score -1):

No decurtated term was found, but 
*[extracurricular activity](http://thesaurus.com/browse/extracurricular+activity)* synonyms are:

- after-school activity
- extraclassroom activity
- noncollegiate activity
- nonscholastic activity

Comment: I said after-school and nonscholastic yesterday.  The other two don't make sense.

Comment: Sorry but the thesaurus gave the definitions -your disagreement is with them.  Also, I clearly stated all the thesaurus terms offered as a summary without edit to clarify the limited choice

Comment: So your answers are just copied from a thesaurus without context?  What thesaurus gives you noncollegiate activity?

Comment: Question: "Does “extra-curricular activities” have a short term?" My answer: "No decurtated term was found" I hope this clarifies your confusion. :-)